# postgresql jmeter for cursors

Tags: postgresql, jmeter

I have the below stored procedure:

```
           CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_employee(
            in_emp_id integer
                  )
             RETURNS refcursor  AS $$

               DECLARE
              ref_cursor REFCURSOR := 'mycursor';
              BEGIN
                OPEN ref_cursor FOR select 
            emp_id,emp_name,emp_salary,date_joined 
               from employee where emp_id=in_emp_id;   -- Open a cursor
             RETURN (ref_cursor);      
                 END;

               $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now I am calling the function as below.

```
                BEGIN;
                  SELECT get_employee(123);
                 FETCH 4   from   mycursor; 
                    COMMIT;
```

Now when I am trying to run jmeter script for l,oad testing this function, there is no way I can write all these commands in that. Can anyone help ?
I have read this link but it doesnt show any output in jmeter view results tres, so couldn't confirm if the test is runnign fine or not.
https://medium.com/@jackliusr/jmeter-calls-stored-procedure-of-postgresql-which-return-cursors-882272e398f1

Comment: Could you show the structure of your test plan?

Answer (score 1):

Check what you set in the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) the `Query Type` as `Callable Statement` and use the `CALL` command to invoke the stored procedure.

1. Add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to your test plan (but use it only for debugging).
2. Run the test.

In the View Results Tree you should see your requests and their responces.

Check this tutorials for more information:

- [Build db test plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [JMeter database Testing](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/07/jmeter-database-testing/)